# sed two pattern search and append line after the last occurence of the second pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk, grep

The following `sed` question has been giving me a lot of headaches over the last 2 days.

I have the following file *(iptables)*:

```
someline

someline

*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

someline
```

I want to use `sed` to search for the pattern `*filter` and if matched then search for a second pattern `[0:0]` and then add a line after the last occurrence of the second pattern.

This would then (ideally) lead to:

```
someline

someline

*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

TESTLINEADDEDBYSED

someline
```

The forum here had given me a good start, but I just can't crack this specific issue.

I so far have the following solution, but it adds the line after the first occurrence of the second pattern `[0:0]`:

```
sed -n '/\*filter/{:a;N;/^\n/s/^\n//;/\[0:0\]/{!ba;p;s/.*/TESTLINEADDEDBYSED/;};ba}; p' file
```

I was under the assumption that with `.*` in the second branch I would consume (read: skip?) the first occurrence of `[0:0]`?
What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```bsh
fgrep -q '*filter' file && tac file|awk '!f&&/\[0:0\]/{$0="FOO\n\n"$0;f=1}1'|tac
someline

someline

*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

FOO

someline
```

First `fgrep` for the fixed string `*filter` in `file` and if it is found insert the line `FOO` after the last line containing `[0:0]`. `tac` is used to read the file in reverse so you don't need to read the file twice or buffer to find the last occurrence as it's easier to find the first occurrence.

---

If the size of the file isn't very large a two pass approach using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if($0~/*filter/)a=1;if(a&&$0~/\[0:0\]/)b=NR;next}FNR==b{$0=$0"\n\nFOO"}1' file file

someline

someline

*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

FOO

someline
```

Comment: although my first idea was to use sed only, I must admit that I love this simple and elegant approach as well. thanks!

Comment: Sometimes chaining existing utilities can be a simpler approach, I have added a two pass method using only `awk` to my answer for contrast.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach since `sed` is terrible with newlines...

Basically, I put everything in one row, replacing newlines with a `@`, do my substitution using greedy match and finally put the newlines back again...

```
$ cat input | tr '\n' '@' | sed s'/\(\*filter.*\[0:0\]\)/@@\1@TESTLINEADDEDBYSED/' | tr '@' '\n'
someline

someline


*filter

:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]

:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

TESTLINEADDEDBYSED

someline
```

A bad approach if the number of lines in file is large!

Comment: So the answer lies in making one big line (with seperator characters), then editing the line and afterwards breaking it up again in multiple lines? Very interesting! Thanks!!

Comment: @sudo_O - outch that hurts! I'm usually the one handling out UUoC-awards :-)

Comment: @cybernijntje - Glad you liked it. Don't forget to upvote :-)

Comment: @Fredrik haha `;)` don't forget the OPs rep isn't high enough to vote yet!

Comment: @sudo_O - true. +1 to you tough even if I'm hurt